# Cambiar de activities deslizando sobre la pantalla

Tags: android

tengo una aplicación que tiene 3 activities y quiero pasar entre ellas deslizando sobre la pantalla. Estuve intentando pero no me sale, como puedo hacer? Ya tengo las 3 activities hechas, cada una con sus funciones, quiero comunicarlas deslizando.
Gracias

Comment: agrega lo que intentaste pero definitivamente lo que se debe hacer es cambiar a Fragments tus Activities y agregarlas en un ViewPager, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La opción ideal para realizar lo que deseas es tener una Actividad que contenga un [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), las 3 Activities debes cambiarlas a Fragments y estos Fragments agregalos a tu [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)** puedes encontrar un ejemplo para lo que deseas.